# How to use freezed with floor database in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, freezed, flutter-freezed

[Freezed](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed) uses `const factory` contructor that doesn't work along with [floor](https://pub.dev/packages/floor) library.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

As of today, they are not working together